# PHP File upload not working on AWS server - mkdir returning false

Tags: php, ajax, file, amazon-web-services, file-upload

I have some code that uploads a file on AWS server. It was working fine until today, I decided to delete all code from my AWS server, and uploaded the latest copy of code, and it has stopped working from then on. Can someone please spot the error.

I tried to debug it a little bit, I found that mkdir(...) function is returning false. I don't know why it is returning false. I have all the permissions on my "uploads" folder - drwxrwxr-x. I am also using enctype="multipart/form-data" on my form.

Can someone please point me out in the right direction? I will do the rest.

Thanks. Please help!

```
$uniqueKey = md5(microtime(true)).uniqid();
$ret = array();

function makedir($dir){
    if (!is_dir($dir) && strlen($dir)>0){
        mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
        chmod($dir, 0777);
    }
}

$output_dir = "../uploads/".$uniqueKey."/";
makedir($output_dir);

if(isset($_FILES["myfile"])){
    $error =$_FILES["myfile"]["error"];
    $ret['unique'] = $uniqueKey;
    $ret['error'] = $error;

    if(!is_array($_FILES["myfile"]["name"])){
        $fileName = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir.$fileName);
        $ret[]= $fileName;
    }else{
        $fileCount = count($_FILES["myfile"]["name"]);
        for($i=0; $i < $fileCount; $i++){
            $fileName = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"][$i];
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"][$i],$output_dir.$fileName);
            $ret[]= $fileName;
        }
    }
}
echo json_encode($ret);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the permissions. I changed the permission pf my folder from drwxrwxr-x to drwxrwxrwx, and it worked.